# Can anyone help me figure out the cause of a recurring VIDEO_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_INTERNAL BSoD error?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Below I have pasted the output of the `analyze -v` command in WinDbg. This BSoD seems to be recurring, happening every few days or so as far as I can recall. <s>In my Minidump folder the date of the second newest dump file is 22/11/2019 but I'm fairly sure that there has been more BSoDs between then and the latest which is dated 02/01/2020.</s> EDIT: I misread or missed some dates and the folder was sorted alphabetically instead of chronologically..even knowing this it seems like there have likely been some BSoDs that did not generate a dump for some reason. The latest and second latest dumps are from 07/01/2020 and 02/01/2020 respectively.

It seems like this error only occurs while I have the game Guild Wars 2 running, but minimised. I suppose it may be worth noting that I recently updated my Nvidia gfx driver, but this has happened both before and after said driver update. Please let me know if there is anything I can do (like running some other commands) to provide more info.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\010220-12562-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 18362 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff802`72c00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff802`73048130
Debug session time: Thu Jan  2 21:43:34.827 2020 (UTC + 0:00)
System Uptime: 4 days 2:45:33.533
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
......
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..............................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
4: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

VIDEO_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_INTERNAL (10e)
The video memory manager encountered a condition that it can't recover from. By crashing,
the video memory manager is attempting to get enough information into the minidump such that
somebody can pinpoint what lead to this condition.
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000002e, The subtype of the bugcheck:
Arg2: ffffd487a0d37b70
Arg3: ffffd4879fe7d5a0
Arg4: ffffd301bc0ed1a0

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for win32k.sys

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Alienware 14

SYSTEM_SKU:  Alienware 14

SYSTEM_VERSION:  A09

BIOS_VENDOR:  Alienware

BIOS_VERSION:  A09

BIOS_DATE:  04/23/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Alienware

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  07MJ2Y

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  A01

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 2e

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffd487a0d37b70

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd4879fe7d5a0

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffd301bc0ed1a0

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x10e_2e

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 9be

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 25'00000000 (cache) 25'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-H3MCRTL

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  01-06-2020 17:18:39.0531

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 x86fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff802872941a0 to fffff80272dc14e0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd301`bc0ed138 fffff802`872941a0 : 00000000`0000010e 00000000`0000002e ffffd487`a0d37b70 ffffd487`9fe7d5a0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffd301`bc0ed140 fffff802`8b053aaa : ffffd487`9fe7d5a0 ffffd487`a0d37b70 ffff9300`4e766000 00000000`00000000 : watchdog!WdLogEvent5_WdCriticalError+0xe0
ffffd301`bc0ed180 fffff802`8b0caa6f : ffffd487`a0d37b70 ffffa804`cb1ce000 ffff9300`4e766000 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange+0xc8ba
ffffd301`bc0ed1d0 fffff802`8b09da22 : ffff9300`4e766000 ffffa804`cb1ce000 ffffd487`a5595400 ffffd487`af4aa4a0 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_PAGE_TABLE_BASE::FreeCpuVisibleAddress+0x2d243
ffffd301`bc0ed200 fffff802`8b09d9bd : ffffa804`cfd02410 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000004 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_PAGE_TABLE_BASE::FreeDriverUpdateAddress+0x46
ffffd301`bc0ed230 fffff802`8b0cce3f : 00000000`00000000 ffff9300`4e766000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000002 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_PAGE_TABLE::UpdatePageTableInvalidate+0xf9
ffffd301`bc0ed300 fffff802`8b09eb38 : 00000000`00000002 ffffd487`af513910 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_PAGE_TABLE::CommitVirtualAddressRange+0x2d18f
ffffd301`bc0ed3e0 fffff802`8b09dd13 : ffffd487`af513910 ffffd487`a5595400 ffffd301`bc0ed640 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_PAGE_DIRECTORY::CommitVirtualAddressRange+0x9c8
ffffd301`bc0ed580 fffff802`8b0d99b7 : ffff272e`c6fb704f 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!CVirtualAddressAllocator::CommitVirtualAddressRange+0x2e3
ffffd301`bc0ed6f0 fffff802`8b0c94b2 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000076 ffffd487`af6879f0 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::InitPagingProcessVaSpace+0x19e23
ffffd301`bc0ed870 fffff802`8b0b81a7 : ffffd487`a5004510 ffffd487`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffd487`b1016938 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_GLOBAL::ProcessSystemCommand+0x2dd12
ffffd301`bc0ed9e0 fffff802`8b0b6ee9 : ffffd487`a5004510 ffffa804`c22b8301 ffff9300`4b6c0100 00000000`00000000 : dxgmms2!VIDMM_WORKER_THREAD::Run+0x12a7
ffffd301`bc0edbe0 fffff802`72d2a7a5 : ffffa804`d4286040 fffff802`8b0b6ee0 ffffd487`a5004510 00000000`00000001 : dxgmms2!VidMmWorkerThreadProc+0x9
ffffd301`bc0edc10 fffff802`72dc8b2a : ffff9300`4b6c0180 ffffa804`d4286040 fffff802`72d2a750 00000000`0000029e : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffffd301`bc0edc60 00000000`00000000 : ffffd301`bc0ee000 ffffd301`bc0e8000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x2a


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  57b2eae858360b0125b5917b867de0f1dbca022c

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  a024e9c0fc452d937d652e67e5ed8ed827e23d1c

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  21e3e42e3af0d727b38397faeefdbf4c1c547d3c

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange+c8ba
fffff802`8b053aaa 90              nop

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  3801e990

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  2

SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange+c8ba

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: dxgmms2

IMAGE_NAME:  dxgmms2.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.18362.449

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  c8ba

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x10e_2e_dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange

BUCKET_ID:  0x10e_2e_dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x10e_2e_dxgmms2!VIDMM_CPU_HOST_APERTURE::UnmapRange

TARGET_TIME:  2020-01-02T21:43:34.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  535

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  784

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  1980-01-11 15:53:20

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  73d5

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x10e_2e_dxgmms2!vidmm_cpu_host_aperture::unmaprange

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ebf2c813-41e1-4d73-9be7-00c514787ed3}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-dxgmms2-sys-bsod-error-on-windows-computer

Comment: Well, I don't think any of that stuff has helped me...`dxdiag` doesn't show any problems and says I have DirectX 12 installed. As for drivers, like I said in my question I updated to the latest Nvidia recently and this has happened both before and after the update. I also notice that that page you linked doesn't mention the BSoD stopcode (or whatever you call it) that I am getting; the `VIDEO_MEMORY_MANAGEMANT_INTERNAL`. Are there some other commands or things that I can use to help?  (TBC in another comment because character limits.)

Comment: This is my first time using WinDbg in a long time so I'm a noob at it again. I noticed in a question I posted years ago about a different error that I used some commands like `!thread`, `dps` and `!irp` so I'm wondering could any of that stuff be useful in investigating this problem?

Comment: I searched dxgmms2 which is the faulting symbol name.

Comment: I googled dxgmms2 and found this https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-dxgmms2-sys-bsod-error-on-windows-computer

I noticed the section that talks about editing the registry...what I'd like to know is are there any general performance implications of setting the TdrDelay value to 10?

Comment: UPDATE: Oh, I just noticed that that's the same article you linked...must've missed the RegEdit thing last time..